# Keras generator with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imagedatagenerator

I am attempting to build a CNN with multiple outputs.  My data generator is as follows:

```
     datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
     train_generator = datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, yt_train, y_on_deck_train, yt_on_deck_train, batch_size=26, shuffle=True)
     test_generator = datagen.flow(X_test, y_test, yt_test, y_on_deck_test, yt_on_deck_test, batch_size=15, shuffle=True)
```

My model statements are as follows:

```
    out_00 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(home_cards.columns), activation='sigmoid', name='y')(x)
    out_01 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(home_cards.columns), activation='sigmoid', name='yt')(x)
    out_02 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(home_cards.columns), activation='sigmoid', name='y_on_deck')(x)
    out_03 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(home_cards.columns), activation='sigmoid', name='yt_on_deck')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[out_00, out_01, out_02, out_03])
    # opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.00005, momentum=0.6, nesterov=False, name='SGD')
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam')

    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(config.CLASH_PATH() + '/models/step_02.h5', monitor='accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    early = EarlyStopping(monitor='accuracy', patience=150, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=0.2,
                                  patience=15, min_lr=0.001, verbose=1)

    loss = {'y': 'binary_crossentropy',
            'yt': 'binary_crossentropy',
            'y_on_deck': 'binary_crossentropy',
            'yt_on_deck': 'binary_crossentropy',
            }

    metrics = {'y': 'accuracy',
               'yt': 'accuracy',
               'y_on_deck': 'accuracy',
               'yt_on_deck': 'accuracy',
               }

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)
    model.summary()

    model.fit(train_generator,
              validation_data=test_generator,
              epochs=1000, verbose=1,
              callbacks=[checkpoint, early, reduce_lr])
```

Unfortunately I am receiving the following error when I attempt to run:

```
TypeError: flow() got multiple values for argument 'batch_size'
```

I am attempting to find an example online to replicate, but unfortunately there are few examples that are multi-label and multi-output.  Thank you!

Comment: Could it maybe be from assigning `datagen` two different batch sizes? You assigned the train set 26 and the test set 15 yet they derive from the same datagen.

Comment: This is working ok in the single output example.  I have made the batch_size equivalent with no impact to the error message.

Comment: Do you need to use `ImageDataGenerator`? Could you just pass the arrays themselves? Or do you need to use data augmentations?

Comment: I need to use a generator to prevent memory errors in use of my GPU since I have large datasets.

Comment: Have you tried passing a subset of the dataset to the GPU without `ImageDataGenerator`? Like maybe 5-10% of it to see if it works.

Comment: Yes...I'm able to train my model with a subset.  It's not an issue with my model..only the generator aspect.

Comment: I'm not asking about the model, I'm specifically asking about the generator because I think it's being used incorrectly...

Comment: It's working correctly for a single output. It's only the multiple output layer amendment that is creating the error.

Comment: Even if you don't use `ImageDataGenerator`, the data is loaded and processed in batches unless you make the batch size equal to the total data size. So I'm trying to figure out why exactly you're using `ImageDataGenerator`. The issue is most likely coming from there because that's where the `batch_size` argument is coming from.

Comment: This is not my experience.  When I am not using a generator, cuda is throwing an out of memory error.  I am using the requisite memory management switches for tensorflow.

Comment: Then your batch size was too high

Comment: The batch size has not been modified and my code is working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only memory management tensorflow offers is limiting growth and setting static amount. Neither are influenced by whether you use a generator or not. You're getting an error about multiple batch_size but want to look everywhere else but the only place that has a workable batch_size parameter? Just look at your code for `.flow()` and compare to the documentation on `ImageDataGenerator.flow()`, you're using it incorrectly...

Comment: For further clarification, OP is incorrectly passing keyword arguments and positional arguments in `ImageDataGenerator`. OP also is trying to pass four elements as input instead of grouping them correctly according to the documentation: `Input data. Numpy array of rank 4 or a tuple. If tuple, the first element should contain the images and the second element another numpy array or a list of numpy arrays that gets passed to the output without any modifications.` OP is setting `batch_size=yt_train` AND `batch_size=26`, and doing similar in the next line. OP is setting `shuffle=yt_on_deck_train`.

Comment: OP is doing similar in the next line. While you may have had some success doing single output(?) what you have in the original question is full of mistakes, and while I've been trying to figure out why these mistakes persist in the OP, instead OP is defensive. The OOM errors still have nothing to do with the use of a generator or not...that's still a batch_size issue. If you want to use those four elements as input, they need to be together as a tuple, which you are not doing. You're passing them as arguments.

Comment: "I have made the batch_size equivalent with no impact to the error message." This should've been evident enough that the issue is exactly with your `.flow()` datasets being defined incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The following modification (insertion of a modified generator) addressed my issue:

```
    def make_multi_output_flow(image_gen, X, y_list, batch_size):
        y_item_0 = y_list[0]
        y_indices = np.arange(y_item_0.shape[0])
        orig_flow = image_gen.flow(X, y=y_indices, batch_size=batch_size)

        while True:
            (X, y_next_i) = next(orig_flow)
            y_next = [y_item[y_next_i] for y_item in y_list]
            yield X, y_next

    new_y_train = [y_train.values, yt_train.values, y_on_deck_train.values, yt_on_deck_train.values]
    multi_output_flow_train = make_multi_output_flow(datagen, X_train, new_y_train, batch_size=36)

    new_y_test = [y_test.values, yt_test.values, y_on_deck_test.values, yt_on_deck_test.values]
    multi_output_flow_test = make_multi_output_flow(datagen, X_train, new_y_test, batch_size=16)

...


    model.fit(multi_output_flow_train,
              validation_data=multi_output_flow_test,
              epochs=1000, verbose=1,
              callbacks=[checkpoint, early, reduce_lr])
```